# How can I fix a Ubuntu upgrade when it was interrupted by a power outage?

Tags: boot

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I was upgrading to Ubuntu 12, then the 
power died and I fixed the broken packages. The system asked to reboot but now I am unable to boot (hangs during boot sequence).

I am able to get into terminal and have mc to view files.
I have tried previous versions under the advanced boot, but all fail to load.

Can someone point me in the right direction to find out what went wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Ubuntu 12.10 as a LIVE-CD/DVD/USB.
Try to click on "Upgrade" then, when it's up or just make a whole new and fresh install!

Answer (score 1):

It has happened to me before. No fix seems to work 100%, because your repositories are probably mixed between old and new. I sugest you to back up your home and do a Fresh, Clean install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. I had power go out while it was upgrading. I booted in safe mode of an earlier version. At that point, it automatically asks for fixing broken packages. I waited for it to finish and was able to bring it to command-line mode. The boot sequence seems to hang, but press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter user/password. After that enter startx on command line - it brings up GUI.
I am still looking how to bring it straight to the gui mode rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then startx.